# Angular does not accept string variable as object key

Tags: angular

Unfortunatelly I can't find answer or solution.
So: if I use a static string as key, it works - but if I use a variable that gives exactly THE SAME string, Angular does not accept it.

The error message is weird: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type".
(Of course this is NOT true, plus that is not index but key. Anyway.)

[image]

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like

```
this.rendel[adat.kulcs as keyof typeof this.rendel] = adat.v
```

Comment: Wow!  This is working. I check once more. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Please could you tell me is there a solution to declare a class with keys of the 'rendel' object, and then import and use that?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, It doesn't allow strings.

You should say that it's not an only string, it's one of the keys of the *rendel* object, so you should create a new interface and update the addItem function as the following

```
interface Rendel {
    alap: string,
    tipus: string,
    felfet: string
}


addItem(adat: {v: string, kulcs: keyof Rendel}) {
        this.rendel[adat.kulcs] = adat.v
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got error message: Property 'addItem' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'..
Weird.